# Kotlin generic class overload?

Tags: generics, kotlin, overloading, variadic

I want to create some classes with variable number of type argument.

For example, a tuple class:

```
class Tuple<T1>{
    //blah 
}
class Tuple<T1,T2>{
    //blah blah 
}
class Tuple<T1,T2,T3>{
    //blah blah blah
}
```

but it shows "redeclaration" error, any suggestion?

Comment: You can't overload classes. You have to give them different names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that, because a Kotlin class must have a unique *fully qualified name* (i.e. its package name plus the simple name `Tuple`).

Depending on what you prefer, you can name those classes following the `TupleN` pattern (`Tuple1`, `Tuple2` etc.) and make a common interface `Tuple`, and also a set of factory functions sharing the name (`tuple(...)`) with different numbers of parameters for creating tuples of different arities:

```
fun <T1> tuple(t1: T1) = Tuple1(t1)

fun <T1, T2> tuple(t1: T1, t2: T2) = Tuple2(t1, t2)

fun <T1, T2, T3> tuple(t1: T1, t2: T2, t3: T3) = Tuple3(t1, t2, t3)

/* ... */
```

Having faced a similar problem, I personally resorted to [generating](https://github.com/h0tk3y/better-parse/blob/master/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/TupleCodegen.kt) the [`TupleN` classes](https://github.com/h0tk3y/better-parse/blob/master/src/commonMain/kotlin/generated/tuples.kt) that I needed.